# App Insights returns error: This expression cannot follow pipe ('|')

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

The following query in App Insights returns no real result but instead an error:

> "This expression cannot follow pipe ('|')"
>   pageViews |  url, duration, timestamp

I mean I took this from a toturial and I dont know why it should not work.

Comment: Hi there, did my answer help you or did you run into other problems?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. After each pipe you will need to perform an action, like if you want to display these columns you should use [project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour#projecthttpsdocsloganalyticsioquerylanguagequerylanguageprojectoperatorhtml-select-rename-and-compute-columns):

```
pageViews | project url, duration, timestamp
```